# Why is my Salesforce Lightning URL hack working for some fields and not others?

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am writing a custom button in Salesforce Lightning.  I am using a URL hack to create a new record and add default values to some fields.  This is working for some fields but not others.  The fields where it is not working are Master-Detail and Lookup Data Types.  In those cases, when the new record comes in the dialog box, the whole field is missing, rather than being filled in. Here is an example:

/lightning/o/ServiceParticipation__c/new?nooverride=true&recordTypeId=01231000001AkRk&defaultFieldValues=Case_Record__c={!Enrollment__c.Case_Record__c}

Note that I have successfully filled in other fields with nooverride and the Record Type.  Let me know if anyone has had this problem and possible solutions.  I have done an exhaustive Internet search.

I have used this syntax successfully with Picklist data types and Number data types.  It could be that the data type is unrelated but it is the only correlation with the problem I have so far.  As I said, when the form comes up, the whole field is missing from the form, including the label.